# HTML style tags that do not support in pdf

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm loading .html file into **RTE(Rich Text Editor)** ,  then Once I click Save as PDF button its saving as PDF

this is view of RTE editor content

[image]

Once I click save as PDF and open it through adobe pdf reader , I'm getting this kind PDF

[image]

its a unformatted structure with missing sections , what can I do to get exact view that existing in RTE editor content

this is RTE editor content loading html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>   
</head>  
<body>  
    <div id="header" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';background-color: black;color: white;text-align: center;padding: 5px;">  
        <h1 style="font-family:'Segoe UI';color: white;text-align: center;">Bank Brochure</h1>  
    </div>  

    <div id="nav" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';line-height: 30px;background-color: #eeeeee;height: 300px;width: 100px;float: left;padding: 5px;">  
        London<br>  
        Paris<br>  
        Tokyo<br>  
    </div>  

    <div id="section" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';float: left;padding: 10px;color:black">  
        <h2>London</h2>  
        <p>  
            London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom,  
            with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.  
        </p>  
        <p>  
            Standing on the River Thames, London has been a major settlement for two millennia,  
            its history going back to its founding by the Romans, who named it Londinium.  
        </p>  
    </div>  

    <div id="footer" style="font-family:'Segoe UI';background-color: black;color: white;clear: both;text-align: center;padding: 5px;">  
        Copyright © 2015 Zoo Group , Solution by kelum.  
    </div>  


</body>  
</html>
```

Once I communicate with this RTE editor technical admins they said that because of above html file some styles does not support in pdf .

Is that possible ? if so I'd like to know what are not supporting HTML tag

or Appreciate if can suggest a way to get exact view that existing in RTE editor content as PDF

Comment: try creating all your **HTML** using `<table>` only structure and all **inline-CSS**

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay okay thanks ,worthy to try that too

Answer (score 1):

PDF does not support HTML directly (*).  The HTML layout and styling needs to be converted to PDF syntax to produce something that looks similar.  So this is not a limitation of *some HTML styles not being supported in PDF*. It's rather a limitation of the RTE tool not supporting these in the conversion to PDF.

I have tried converting your HTML sample using iText's XML Worker (disclaimer: I am an iText Software employee). I had to make a small tweak, because XML Worker is based on processing XHTML; the `<br>`'s have to be closed: `<br />`.  With this adjustment, this is what the PDF looks like:

[image: PDF screenshot]

(*) Ignoring rich text in form fields, which seems out of scope for this question.

Comment: so if I use iText worker will I able to convert this RTE editor content  to PDF properly ?